# JPA persistence and Hibernate javassist objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play Framework v.1.2.6 for a project and I have issues with hibernation of objects when i am trying to retrieve them from database.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/jpa

I have a query which selects rows from a mysql table and in the result there are proxy objects. Please see image below.[image]

I am not using any Hibernate configuration file. I am using only @Annotations in my model class.

Example of my query:

```
static List<User> getAllUsersFromAccount(Account account) {
    return  User.find(
            "SELECT u " +
            "FROM User u " +
            "WHERE u.account=?", 
            account).fetch();
}
```

Does anyone knows how can i avoid getting proxy objects in the query results?

For now we iterate over the array of users and check if the entity is instanceof HibernateProxy. We do not want to do that because maybe we have the same problem and for other queries.

```
private static <T> T initializeAndUnproxy(T entity) {
    Hibernate.initialize(entity);
    if(entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        entity = (T)((HibernateProxy)entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: Its a good question with or without context, but would you mind explaining anyway why you are asking this? Is it to prevent lazy init errors later on?

Comment: When my code attempts to serialize the class I get errors like "Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?."
We have querying and serializing all over the project and works fine. I just seems to be happening with this user query result only which is very strange.

Comment: That sounds more like there is something in the entity which isn't serializable to be honest. Do you have any properties that are made Transient (as in: not-persisted)?

Comment: I have just update the question description. I provide a temporary fix to our problem by iterating over the user objects. We do not want to do that because maybe we have the same problem in other queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JOIN FETCH keyword in you JPQL/HQL query. In you example, if you don't want to deal with proxy objects instead of real Account objects add 'JOIN FETCH u.account'

```
static List<User> getAllUsersFromAccount(Account account) {
    return  User.find(
            "SELECT u " +
            "FROM User u " +
            "JOIN FETCH u.account " +
            "WHERE u.account=?", 
            account).fetch();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the User objects are returned as proxy objects which is strange.

Comment: Is it possible that Users with id 102 and 106 were loaded previously in session and proxified?

Comment: I have just update the question description. I provide a temporary fix to our problem by iterating over the user objects. We do not want to do that because maybe we have the same problem in other queries.

Comment: Sometimes hibernate returns proxy loaded entities when using annotations on fields https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=982170&start=0